# Trigonometric Integrals using residue

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need to calculate, for $a \geq 1$,$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iax}sin(x)}{x^2+1}dx$$

Attempt at Solution:
$$Let \ \ f(z)=\frac{e^{iaz}e^{iz}}{z^2+1}=\frac{e^{iz(a+1)}}{z^2+1}$$
This has poles at $z=\pm i$.

I'm going to use Jordan's Lemma, so we only need to consider z=i. Calculating the residue:
$$res(\frac{e^{iz(a+1)}}{(z+i)(z-i)},i)=\frac{e^{-(a+1)}}{2i}$$
Thus:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iaz}e^{iz}}{z^2+1}dz = 2 \pi i \cdot \frac{e^{-(a+1)}}{2i}=\pi e^{a+1}$$

But taking the imaginary part:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iax}sin(x)}{x^2+1}dx=Im(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{iaz}e^{iz}}{z^2+1}dz)=0$$

I don't think this is right? Where's the mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the imaginary part of $e^{iaz }e^{iz}$ is $\sin(a(z-1))$ NOT $e^{iaz }\sin(z)$

Comment: Hint: Make the same calculations for $g(z)=\frac{e^{iaz} e^{-iz}}{1+z^2}$ and then calculate $g(x)+f(x)$

Comment: Does $g(z)+f(z)$ not give me $\frac{2e^{iaz}cos(z)}{1+z^2}$?

Comment: yeah sorry there should be a minus sign obviously, furthermore you have to divide by $2i$ to be absolutely correct.

Comment: Thank you. Is Jack D'Aurizio's answer correct? I think I get the same answer (as does Maple!), but this problem comes from a set called "real integrals", so the fact it's imaginary is worrying me a bit!

Comment: Jack's answer is correct, and can also be verified by a CAS. Please note that your integrand have imaginary components, so it would be a big surprise if they cancel out to zero in any case. i think your lecturer was just a little bit sloppy with his notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $\sin z=\text{Im}\left(e^{iz}\right)$, but $e^{ia z}\sin z \neq \text{Im}\left(e^{iaz}\cdot e^{iz}\right)$. Anyway, if you know that:
$$\forall \alpha>0,\qquad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{i\alpha z}}{1+z^2}\,dz = \frac{\pi}{e^{\alpha}},\tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$ \forall a>1,\qquad\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{iax}\sin x}{1+x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{\pi}{e^{a+1}}-\frac{\pi}{e^{a-1}}\right).\tag{2} $$